# CakePHP URL rewriting on IP address with tilt sign (~)

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I am setting up a cakePHP application on a IP address. The domain name hasn't been finalized yet. I am facing problem with URL rewriting and getting a 500 interval.

My website URL looks like this one.

http://11.11.11.111/~username/

My .htaccess file contents are as followings.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/username/public_html/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I would appreciate if somebody help with what am I doing wrong?

Thanks